# XUL: how to render special html entities(copy, trade, deg...)?

Tags: html, firefox, entity, xul

If I just put in label value or anywhere else

```
&trade; or &deg;
```

it will give me parse error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, those entities are defined in HTML, but not in XML in general (unless they're all defined in the DTD, of course) == only `quot`, `amp`, `apos`, `lt`, and `gt`, are "predefined".

Simplest might be to use the general XML way to encode any given codepoint, e.g., `&#176;` for `&deg;` and `&#8482` for `&trade;`.  You can find all the entities and their numerical equivalents in many spots around the web, e.g., [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).